# ROS and Gazebo Integration

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to perform a simulation on my laptop. The detailed explanation of my goal is [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1374/how-to-set-path-between-2-points-and-make-robot-to/?answer=1389#post-id-1389). I wanted to know which of the two ROS integration ways explained in the [tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials#Plugins) would be better for my purpose ?

I have already installed ROS and then Gazebo. Just need to integrate them.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1645/ros-and-gazebo-integration/) by [amit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/166/amit/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

You should create a Gazebo plugin that is ROS enabled: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.4/ros_enabled_model_plugin

The above example is for a model plugin, but you can also make a World Plugin.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/166/amit/) on 2013-03-07**:
Thanks nkoenig.

**Comment by [amit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/166/amit/) on 2013-03-17**:
@nkoenig : In my world model, I have all the models in the .world file and don't have separate models directory. I used the GUI to create my world so the codes were edited in the same .world file. Now if I want to write plugins for .world file, will it be possible ? Also I want to make the robot move from one point to other. Can I do that just by using Gazebo or Do I need to take help from ROS ?
I can post the code of my ".world" file if you want.
Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-03-18**:
You can put plugins in a .world file. You'll need to use ROS to programmatically move a robot.

**Comment by [amit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/166/amit/) on 2013-03-19**:
Thanks again.